# What do I enter into the fields for obtaining a Yahoo API Key?

Tags: rest, soap, yahoo, import-contacts, yahoo-api

It asks for the Application URL and the application Domain what am I supposed to fill in those fields....the formatted suggestions in the form entries are a bit confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking at this page: https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html  It seems pretty clear.

Comment: Yes. what is the difference between the application domain and the application URL and is the application URL just the page on my site where i import contacts e.g. www.sitename.com/pageImportContacts? what is the application domain?

Comment: The domain is just the first part: http://www.sitename.com     and the URL is the whole thing.  I'm not sure why they break it out, maybe to support redirects or proxy servers.

Answer (score 0):

The Application URL is typically the homepage of your app, something users could visit to learn what it does.

The Application Domain is used in the OAuth flow to return users to your app after approving access. Typically this should just be the domain, then you'll specify the actual redirect URL in the OAuth call.

For example:

Application URL: http://www.example.com/myapp/
Application Domain: http://www.example.com